# backbone model set value does not fire change event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection and a table view for this collection.

```
App.Views.TableContainer = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#some-table,

    clearTable: function(){
        this.collection.each(function(person){
            person.set('deleteMe', 1);
        });
    }    
});
```

The view for each row in the table:

```
App.Views.PersonRow = App.Views.BaseViewTemplate.extend({
    template: template("person-row-template"),
    tagName: 'tr',

    events: {
        'click' : 'removeFromTable'
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.model.on('change', this.removeRow(), this);
    },

    removeRow: function(){
        console.log('removing');
        console.log(this.model.toJSON());
        if(this.model.get('deleteMe') == 1){
            this.$el.remove();
            App.publisherTableContainer.removeFromContainer(this.model);
        }

    },

    removeFromTable: function(e){
        var me = this;
        this.$el.fadeOut(300);
        App.personTableContainer.removeFromContainer(this.model);

    }
});
```

when executing clearTable of TableContainer, the function removeRow of PersonRow is not executing (sadly)

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Roy

Comment: What is the output of the `console.log`?

Comment: `Backbone.View.extend({el: '#some-table,`, there is a quote `'` missing, typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is: (and this is a common one and probably why your change function is not working)

```
this.model.on('change', this.removeRow(), this);
```

Should be:

```
this.model.on('change', this.removeRow, this);
```

The on functions second parameter should be a callback function. Right now you are sending in whatever is returned by removeRow. This would work if the function is in fact returning a callback function but I guess it's not in this case :)

Comment: The first is certainly only a typo, no need to mention it. But his problem more than surely comes from the second error. Explain why it should be without the parenthesis though, it may be not clear for the OP.